# XSLT code for Creating parent of a group of elements if the specified children exist in that node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My sample XML document with namespace:

```
<TXLife xmlns="some web address" Version="2.22.00">
<TXLifeRequest>
    <TransRefGUID>2345678</TransRefGUID>
    <!--*so many children in hierarchy *
....
.......-->
    <Vector>
        <VectorType>Base Premium</VectorType>
        <cd>1<cd>
        <V>4659.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>               
        <V>656.00</V>
        <V>656.00</V>
        <V>656.00</V>
        <!--  .................-->
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>9735.50</V>
        <V>9735.50</V>
    </Vector>
    <Vector>
        <VectorType>SLI Rider Premium</VectorType>
    </Vector>
    <Vector>
        <VectorType>DWP Rider Premium</VectorType>
    </Vector>
</TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>
```

I want an XML output where ,if Vector Element has got V children, they should be grouped in a single parent named as **Group**,else print as they are.
Vector has got other two elements **VectorType** and **cd**. These elements should not be affected.

I am a newbie in XSLT and here is my code which is not Working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Vector/V">
    <xsl:element name="Group">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | node()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help

**Expected Output:**

```
<TXLife xmlns="some web address" Version="2.22.00">
<TXLifeRequest>
    <TransRefGUID>2345678</TransRefGUID>
    <!--*so many children in hierarchy *
....LEAVE THEM AS THEY ARE
.......-->
    <Vector>
        <VectorType tc="1">Base Premium</VectorType>

        <!--All V elements go in a single group-->
        <Group>
        <V>4659.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>
        <V>159.50</V>               
        <V>656.00</V>
        <V>656.00</V>
        <V>656.00</V>
        <!--  .................-->
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>4808.00</V>
        <V>9735.50</V>
        <V>9735.50</V>

        </Group>
    </Vector>
    <Vector>
        <VectorType>SLI Rider Premium</VectorType>
    </Vector>
    <Vector>
        <VectorType>DWP Rider Premium</VectorType>
    </Vector>
</TXLifeRequest>
```

The Vector Element with so many children V ,re-occurs.

Comment: Could you please post the expected output.

Comment: Sure Murthy, Editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this stylesheet work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="some web address" exclude-result-prefixes="ns" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:Vector/ns:V[1]">
        <Group xmlns="some web address">
            <xsl:copy-of select="../ns:V"/>
        </Group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:Vector/ns:V" priority="0"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And if the order of elements does not matter, you can replace the `2nd` and `3rd` template above with the following one:

```
<xsl:template match="ns:Vector">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::ns:V)]"/>
    <Group xmlns="some web address">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:V"/>
    </Group>
</xsl:template>
```